# Applying conditional to a subset of rows where rows are different formats in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to flag rows in a dataset where all entries in a subset of columns are NA. The caveat to this is that some rows are strings and some are numbers.

Doing this with columns that are all numbers works fine. Let's say we want an indicator variable that tells us whether columns a to c in the following dataset are all NA

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,4,5,NA),
                 b = c(NA,4,2,NA),
                 c = c(3,7,8,NA),
                 d = c(2,1,1,1))

df

# output
   a  b  c d
1  1 NA  3 2
2  4  4  7 1
3  5  2  8 1
4 NA NA NA 1
```

Using `dplyr` we can create a variable indicating what we need

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
    mutate(allNA = case_when(all(is.na(c_across(cols = a:c))) ~ "allNA",
                             TRUE ~ "notAllNA")) %>%
      ungroup()

# output
# A tibble: 4 × 5
      a     b     c     d allNA   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1     1    NA     3     2 notAllNA
2     4     4     7     1 notAllNA
3     5     2     8     1 notAllNA
4    NA    NA    NA     1 allNA
```

But if one of the variables is a string instead of a number

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,4,5,NA),
                 b = c(NA,"ava","dillion",NA),
                 c = c(3,7,8,NA),
                 d = c(2,1,1,1))

df

# output
   a       b  c d
1  1    <NA>  3 2
2  4     ava  7 1
3  5 dillion  8 1
4 NA    <NA> NA 1
```

The same code throws the following error

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `allNA = case_when(...)`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `vec_c()`:
! Can't combine `a` <double> and `b` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One option to achieve your desired result which allows for columns of different types would be to use `rowSums` with `across`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>%
  mutate(allNA = if_else(
    rowSums(across(a:c, ~ !is.na(.x))) == 0, "allNA", "notAllNA"
  ))
#>    a       b  c d    allNA
#> 1  1    <NA>  3 2 notAllNA
#> 2  4     ava  7 1 notAllNA
#> 3  5 dillion  8 1 notAllNA
#> 4 NA    <NA> NA 1    allNA
```

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to use `if_all`:

```
mutate(df, allNA = if_all(a:c, is.na))
   a       b  c d allNA
1  1    <NA>  3 2 FALSE
2  4     ava  7 1 FALSE
3  5 dillion  8 1 FALSE
4 NA    <NA> NA 1  TRUE
```

---

You can then modify accordingly using `ifelse`

```
df %>%
  mutate(allNA = if_else(if_all(a:c, is.na), 'allNA', 'notAllNA'))

   a       b  c d    allNA
1  1    <NA>  3 2 notAllNA
2  4     ava  7 1 notAllNA
3  5 dillion  8 1 notAllNA
4 NA    <NA> NA 1    allNA
```

Comment: All the answers were great but you can only award it to one and this seems the neatest.

Answer (score 1):

Some more variants in addition to @stefan's answer :

**1. `c_across`**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(, as.character)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(allNA = case_when(all(is.na(c_across(cols = a:c))) ~ "allNA",
                           TRUE ~ "notAllNA")) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

    a b           c     d allNA   
  <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <chr>   
1     1 NA          3     2 notAllNA
2     4 ava         7     1 notAllNA
3     5 dillion     8     1 notAllNA
4    NA NA         NA     1 allNA
```

**2. `pmap`**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(allNA = pmap(select(., a:c), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(c(...))), "allNA", "notAllNA")))

    a b           c     d allNA   
  <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <chr>   
1     1 NA          3     2 notAllNA
2     4 ava         7     1 notAllNA
3     5 dillion     8     1 notAllNA
4    NA NA         NA     1 allNA
```

**3. `pivot_longer()` with `values_transform()`**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = a:c, names_to = "key", values_to = "val", values_transform = list(val = as.character)) %>%
  group_by(row_id) %>% 
  summarize(allNA = all(is.na(val))) %>% 
  right_join(df %>% 
               mutate(row_id = row_number()), by = "row_id") %>% 
  select(-row_id)

 allNA     a b           c     d
  <lgl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE     1 NA          3     2
2 FALSE     4 ava         7     1
3 FALSE     5 dillion     8     1
4 TRUE     NA NA         NA     1
```

Comment: Thank you @TarJae. What does `type.convert(as.is=T) do?

Comment: with values_transform we transform all to character class. R guesses depending on the elements of each column which class this column should be. E.g. if you have character column 1,2,3,4,5 type.convert(as.is = TRUE) will transform it to numeric!